# To find ";" then delete spaces up to next character

Tags: awk

I have many lines starting with ";", then 1 or more spaces, followed by some other character(s) on the same line. I need to remove the spaces following the ";" up to but not including the characters that follow.

I tried a few variations of the following code because it worked great on lines with empty spaces, but I am not very familiar with awk.

```
awk '{gsub(/^ +|  +$/,"")}1'  filea>fileb
```

Sample input:

```
;    4
;  group 452
;          ring
```

Output wanted:

```
;4
;group 452
;ring
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove any white space after the first semicolon, try:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^;[[:blank:]]+/, ";")} 1' filea
;4
;group 452
;ring
```

The regex `^;[[:blank:]]+` matches the first semicolon and any blanks or tabs which follow it.  The function `sub` replaces this with `;`.  Since this only occurs once on the line (at the beginning), there is no need for `gsub`.

`[:blank:]` is a unicode-safe way of specifying blank space.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{sub(/^; +/,";")}1' file

;4
;group 452
;ring
```

Comment: While this workw, please provide some explanation on how this works for the benefit of others

Comment: You do a single substitution, so you should use `sub` instead of `gsub`

Answer (score 1):

`sed` would also do :

```
sed -E 's/^(;){1}([[:blank:]]+)/\1/' file
```

The parentheses is used as selectors and a `\number` combination represents the corresponding selection.

In `^(;){1}([[:blank:]]+)` we check for the start of line (`^`) and a `;` that occurs one time(`{1}`), followed by any number of blank characters `([[:blank:]]+)` and then replace the matched pattern with our first selection.

Comment: `(;){1}` is equivalent to `;`

Comment: @oguzismail Yes but making it a selection makes more reusable, say the op can put some other pattern instead of `;`

Comment: Very good.  As the problem requires a simple substitution, `sed` is a natural tool to use here.

Answer (score 0):

This defines the field separator `FS` to be the start of the record followed by a `;` and a set of spaces. It then redefines the output field separator `OFS` to be just a `;`.  The conversion from `FS` to `OFS` is done by reassigning `$1` to itself.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="^; *";OFS=";"}{$1=$1}1'
```

or

```
awk -F'^; *' -vOFS=";" '{$1=$1}1'
```